# Parsing a JSON which condition use

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

i would like to know how i can parse a JSON until there is nothing else ?

here is my code, but i need something else for my condition ...

```
 for (int i = 0; i != 7; i++)
        {
            Boxes *boxes = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Boxes" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            boxes.name =   [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"] ;
            boxes.sexe =   [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"sexe"] ;
            boxes.topic =   [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"topic"] ;
            boxes.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the count of boxesDetail object.

```
int count = [[json objectForKey:@"boxesDetail"] count];
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Boxes *boxes = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Boxes" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            boxes.name =   [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"] ;
            boxes.sexe =   [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"sexe"] ;
            boxes.topic =   [[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"topic"] ;
            boxes.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[json valueForKey:@"boxesDetail"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
        }
```